# include external lib in angular 2 typescript

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to include woocommerce api module in angular 2 but I'm hitting different errors.
The node module can be found here:
[WooCommerce API - Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/woocommerce-api)

And basically it exports a module that has a few methods.
Thing is that I've tried to include the library in the index.html of the angular 2 app and I hit error:

```
require is not defined
```

the lib should obvious run in the nodejs server and not in the client browser so since the file exports a module, I've tried importing it in my component.ts file but I hit again error 404 not found for the lib dependencies.

So my question would be how can I import such a library in angular 2 so I can create new instances of it and call it's methods?